Expressing characteristic function using covariance
If $X$ is a $n$ dimensional random variable the characteristic function is defined by
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega^T x}]= 1 - i\omega^T \mathbb{E}[x] - \frac{1}{2}\omega^T\mathbb{E}[xx^T]\omega + o(\left\lVert \omega \right\rVert^2)
$$
I am wonder if it's possible to write
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{i\omega^T x}]= 1 - i\omega^T \mathbb{E}[x] - \frac{1}{2}\omega^T\Sigma_x \omega + o(\left\lVert \omega \right\rVert^2)
$$
With $\Sigma_x$ being the covariance matrix. I've tried adding and subtracting terms to complete the covariance term but I end up with a left over term which cannot go into $o(\left\lVert \omega \right\rVert^2)$.
Is there an approximation maybe?

In general, the answer is no. Ultimately, when you add and subtract you end up with the term: $\omega^T\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[x]^T\omega$.
From your question, you hope for $\omega^T\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[x]^T\omega=o(\|\omega\|^2)$.
Consider the sequence $\omega_n=\frac{\mathbb{E}[x]}{n\|\mathbb{E}[x]\|}$
We note that $\|\omega_n\|^2=\frac{1}{n}$
Then, $\frac{\omega_n^T\mathbb{E}[x]\mathbb{E}[x]^T\omega_n}{\|\omega_n\|^2}=n^2\frac{\|\mathbb{E}[x]\|^2}{n^2}=O(1)$.
If you focus on a subset of $\omega$ or assume $x$ is mean zero, some approximations can probably used but a priori its not guaranteed

And there's no other construction that takes into account the covariance matrix? The only one I thought was to use $y = x - \mathbb{E}[x]$ and then use the characteristic function there. But the mean contribution disappear obviously

The point i was making in the answer is that you are too restrictive unless you have some restrictions on $\omega$

Such as? What restrictions?

@user8469759, you would need some restriction that is essentially $\omega\in\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is such that $\frac{\mu^T\omega}{|\mu|}\to 0$ as $\omega\to 0$
